# concurrency issue while simulataniously updating many to many in django

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

there is a view which updates entities one with list of entity two are passed.
entity one and two are in a many to many relationship.

To my best understanding and observation it deletes all existing rows and inserts the updated entries in the hidden table connecting the two entities.

When this view is called repeatedly by the browser while testing and in few other conditions not understood clearly the integrity of the connecting table the two entities is broken.

This should happen only when there are two requests happening in parallel in the below order:

1. request 1 deletes entries in the connecting table
2. request 2 deletes entries in the connecting table
3. request 1 inserts updated entries in the connecting table
4. request 2 is unable to insert due to the same unique keys present.

is it possible to make the deletion and insertion atomic for particular user and entity one combination such that integrity is maintained for every patch on entity one for an user?

is my observation right and would you rather suggest simply catching the error and pass execution. would you be sure of the error's origin or be able to regenerate the error?

Comment: Note that Django 1.9 no longer does delete then reassignment ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#related-set-direct-assignment)).